# Fabric.js OSX Safari Rendering Bug (Text/Image Layering Interaction)

Tags: canvas, safari, fabricjs

I run a medium size company that uses a fabric.js application as our primary product. As of today, one of our clients (and our first using OSX safari regularly) has created some pretty interesting bugs, and at present I'm not even sure where to start troubleshooting.

The finished product they posted today is the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVPFa.jpg

Clearly the text is causing the background image to render incorrectly behind it, but I haven't found any record of this bug being reported in the past.

It's worth noting that we haven't modified the actual rendering code of fabric js, just placement and manipulation of objects, and I can say for sure that a canvas.renderAll() has been run before rendering out the image. I'm wondering if maybe this has to do with the fact that the canvas is hidden while the rendering happens?

I will have a mac tomorrow on hand to continue troubleshooting.